# How to select a date range of current month in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select current month rows in table

I have tried this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Test data? Expected outcome? Actual outcome?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on the MySQL engine, but my guess is that you'd be better off in general by comparing the column(s) to actual date values instead of using the date functions that you have. Once you wrap the column(s) in a date function it will make indexes on the column(s) useless.

I don't have a MySQL engine on this machine to test with, but here's some pseudocode:

```
SELECT
    <column list>
FROM
    My_Table
WHERE
    my_date >= <get 1st of current month>(CURDATE()) AND
    my_date <  <get 1st if next month>(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest method which i have tried and works well, you want to select rows where `date_field` is in this month.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_field > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

the above will return all records that the date_field is this month in mysql